# .htaccess RewriteRule without Redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

If the folder contains 2 letters (example: zz) then execute file (foofile) without redirecting to it. foofile's text output is to be shown on the browser.

```
URI accessed by browser:http://www.mysite.com/zz/folder1/file1
File to be executed:    http://www.mysite.com/foofile?var1=zz&var2=/folder1/file1
```

This is not working since the browser shows a 404 (not found) error:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/../.*$
RewriteRule ^/(..)(/.*)$ /foofile?var1=$1&var2=$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove preceding slashes in your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^(..)(/.*)$ foofile?var1=$1&var2=$2
```

And your `RewriteCond` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(..)(/.*)$ /foofile?var1=$1&var2=$2
```

And check apache's error log

You don't need RewriteCond, as the RewriteRule already checks if the URL matches.